# Unable to start activity error when switching between activities

Tags: android

This is the main java code where in i have created a main game menu the settings page i have tried with an xml file:

```
 package com.self;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView c, ng, h, cr, s, e;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.self.R.layout.main);
    c = (TextView) findViewById(com.self.R.id.cont);
    ng = (TextView) findViewById(com.self.R.id.newg);
    h = (TextView) findViewById(com.self.R.id.help);
    cr = (TextView) findViewById(com.self.R.id.credits);
    s = (TextView) findViewById(com.self.R.id.settings);
    e = (TextView) findViewById(com.self.R.id.exit);
    c.setOnClickListener(this);
    ng.setOnClickListener(this);
    h.setOnClickListener(this);
    cr.setOnClickListener(this);
    s.setOnClickListener(this);
    e.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case com.self.R.id.settings:
        Class myclass;
        try {
            myclass = Class.forName("com.self.settings");

            Intent myint = new Intent(main.this, myclass);
            startActivity(myint);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    }

   }

    }
```

and the settings.xml file which is supposed to open when i click on the settings textview in main xml file .

```
   <TextView android:text="@string/sound" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/sound">                             
</TextView>

<TextView android:text="@string/music" android:id="@+id/music"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" style="@style/MenuFont">
</TextView>

<TextView android:text="@string/vibrate" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/vibrate"
    style="@style/MenuFont">
</TextView>
<TextView android:text="@string/graphics"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:id="@+id/graphics" style="@style/MenuFont">
</TextView>
<TextView android:text="@string/back" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"

    android:id="@+id/back" style="@style/MenuFont">
</TextView>

     </LinearLayout>
```

And This is my manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".main" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
      <intent-filter> 
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
      </intent-filter> 
</activity> 
<activity android:name=".settings" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
      <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" /> 
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

This is my Logcat report :

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.self/com.self.settings}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060002 type #0x12 is not valid
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
```

Comment: can u post your log cat?

Comment: Did you specify all your `Activities` in `Manifest` file?

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.self/com.self.settings}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060002 type #0x12 is not valid
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)

Comment: did you add your Activity to your Manifest?

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(438):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)

Comment: yes i added it to the manifest file

Comment: Can you show your settings activity code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the contentview . can you please let me know why have you set the layout as id? `setContentView(com.self.R.id.settings);` besides you should set it as `setContentView(R.layout.settings);`

Comment: have added and checked for the case sensitivity .. the errors are of layout inflater ...

Comment: <activity android:name=".main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".settings"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: package com.self;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class settings extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(com.self.R.id.settings);
 }

 
}

Comment: The issue is with the contentview . can you please let me know why have you set the layout as `id`? `setContentView(com.self.R.id.settings);` besides you should set it as `setContentView(R.layout.settings);`

Comment: oh yes.. thenx ... i mistook it